# Chef docker query

Tags: chef-infra

Below is my recipe for docker. I have installed docker using chef and its installed properly but when i am trying to pull the image through chef its not working:

```rb
# default.rb

package 'docker' do
  action :install
end

service 'default' do
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end

docker_image 'nginx' do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end
```

I am getting below error when running chef client locally and testing:

> NoMethodError
>   undefined method `docker_image' for cookbook: docker, recipe: default :Chef::Recipe

As I am new to chef so need help on above issue

Answer (score 0):

`docker_image` resource is not defined in chef core, so you must provide the source of definition. This resource is defined in `docker` cookbook, which is available in [supermarket](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/docker). So you must depend on that cookbook to use the resource. Add a line into `metadata.rb` of your cookbook:

```rb
# metadata.rb

depends 'docker', '~> 6.0'
```

Then your dependency management engine (Berkshelf, Policyfile) will be able to find and download the cookbook.

Comment: What about running docker container in the same way in the default.rb file? Any cnanges require for that?

Comment: Error below after making changes to metadata.rb:                                            
[2020-06-18T10:27:28+00:00] ERROR: Could not read /root/chef-repo/cookbooks/docker into a Chef object: Cookbook depends on itself in cookbook docker, please remove the this unnecessary self-dependency
[2020-06-18T10:27:28+00:00] ERROR: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.11.8/lib/chef/cookbook/metadata.rb:283:in `depends'
/root/chef-repo/cookbooks/docker/metadata.rb:21:in `from_file'